# Build array in PHP like to JS?

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following array of arrays in JS:

```
var data = [
  ['Year', 'Sales'],
  ['2014', 1000],
  ['2015', 1170],
];
```

How to build this array in PHP  that after use in JS. I tried:

```
$data[] = [2014 => 1000];

echo json_encode($data);
```

I dont know what I do wring, I get this:

[image]

And it is not reproduced in Google Map Bar.

Default array:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Year', 'Sales'],
                ['2014', 1000],
                ['2015', 1170]
            ]);
```

Insted this array I put own:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(model);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
$data = [
    ['Year', 'Sales'],
    ['2014', 1000],
    ['2015', 1170],
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

You want a multi-dimensional array, not an associative array.

Answer (score 3):

`=>` syntax is for creating associative arrays, which are analogous to Javascript objects. But your JS is a 2D array, not an object. The PHP is:

```
$data = array(
    array('Year', 'Sales'),
    array('2014', 1000),
    array('2015', 1170)
);
```

The syntax for adding a new row to the array would be:

```
$data[] = array('2014', 1000);
```

Comment: Or I can us this? `$data[] = [(string)$this->xLabel, (string)$this->yLabel];`?

Comment: @OPV Yes, that would work as well. But you may not need to cast them to strings.

Comment: @OPV In your JS the second element is a number, not a string.

Comment: Edited question